# Retrieve comboBox displayed values

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to retrieve the displayed values of all items present in a `comboBox`.

**First case**: if the comboBox has been filled using a `DataSource`:

```
comboBox.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];
comboBox.DisplayMember = "value";
comboBox.ValueMember = "id";
```

...I use this code:

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in comboBox.Items) {
    String value = rowView.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    // 1 corresponds to the displayed members
    // Do something with value
}
```

**Second case**: if the comboBox has been filled with the `comboBox.Items.Add("blah blah")`, I use the same code, except I have to look in the first dimension of the `ItemArray`:

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in comboBox.Items) {
    String value = rowView.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    // 0 corresponds to the displayed members
    // Do something with value
}
```

Now I would like to be able to retrieve all values without knowing the scheme used to fill the comboBox. Thus, I don't know if I have to use `ItemArray[0]` or `ItemArray[1]`. Is it possible? How could I do that?

Comment: I think you need `comboBox1.SelectedText` or `comboBox1.SelectedValue`

Comment: @V4Vendetta: I am not trying to get the _selected_ item, but to loop through _all_ items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
        string displayedText;
        DataRowView drw = null;

        foreach (var item in comboBox1.Items)
        {
            drw = item as DataRowView;
            displayedText = null;

            if (drw != null)
            {
                displayedText = drw[comboBox1.DisplayMember].ToString();
            }
            else if (item is string)
            {
                displayedText = item.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't have the instinct to use `var` keyword. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Combobox` would be populated with the `DataSource` property in the first case. Therefore its `DataSource` won't be null. In the second case, it would be null. So you could do an if-else with `(comboBox1.DataSource==null)` and then accordingly use `ItemArray[0]` or `ItemArray[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Leito, you could check to see if the DataSource is a DataTable or not to determine which action to take.

```
if (comboBox.DataSource is DataTable)
{
    // do something with ItemArray[1]
}
else
{
    // do something with ItemArray[0]
}
```